# Alternative prrof of $\sqrt 2 $ (and $\sqrt {\text {of any non square integer}}$ ) not being rational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Long time ago for an assignment, I submitted an alternative proof of $\sqrt 2$ not being rational along the following lines:

suppose $\frac{a^2}{b^2}=2$  then we must also have $a=b+n$ for $a,b,n$ positive integers.

$(b+n)^2=2b^2$

$b^2+n^2+2bn=2b^2$

$n^2+2bn-b^2=0$ At this point I managed to somehow show that no integer $n$ can satisfy this ( not sure if I used quadratic equation or not), in place of 2, substituting $k$ in the first equation lead to $n$ not being an integer whenever $k$ was not a square integer. without having to change anything in the proof.

I can not reconstruct the missing steps, what possible continuation in reasoning can work for this case?

Comment: you are back to the start ! you haven't made any progress with this method.

Comment: The first line of your proof is wrong.  If $\frac{a^2}{b^2} > 1$ then $a>b$ so $a + n$ is always strictly greater than $b$ for any positive $n$.  This doesn't necessarily change anything about your proof, however, other than switching $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @A1DHTH not sure what you mean, it worked 20 years ago when I did the assignment.

Comment: @Arjang, if it worked 20 years ago, why are you asking then?

Comment: @iHubble : Cant remember the steps, want to know what would work.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese : thanks, now it is corrected.

Comment: @mickep : I am confused, the link to cuttheknot goes to a complicated trigonometric integral. What am I looking for on that page?

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the wrong link. I meant [this page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml). Maybe you find something here.

Comment: @mickep : Woa! Amazing, so many delightful things there! Thank you, the will keep me busy for  long time to come.